# Installing Ubuntu onto laptop with no os via USB

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

My current laptop has no os installed and I would like to install Ubuntu onto it by tranferring a file/files from my android tablet and booting the setup off of the USB. Any help please?

Comment: Simply create a Live USB with Ubuntu, change your BIOS to boot from USB and install Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  The OP does not have an OS to use to make a Live USB, only an Android tablet.

Comment: @Blade depending on the tablet, it might be easier to have a friend's or maybe a library's computer to download and install the iso to a USB.  It can be a Linux or even a Windows computer.

Comment: @crip659 This question should probably be migrated to Android Stack Exchange with title "How can I download and create a Live USB with my tablet?". If so you can flag and ask a mod to move it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix is there a way to do this without root?

Comment: @Blade You need to post your question under the Answer in the cross site duplicate. But you should search the site first to see if your query is already answered.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix oh okay, so how do i do that? im new to this website so im not sure how things work here

Comment: @Blade I'm not that familiar with the Android Stack Exchange website myself. You can post a new question there asking how to create a Live USB without root powers. In Android OS, even though it's Linux every user file is still defined as owned by root when you view the Android partition from within Ubuntu. That is about all I know...

Comment: @Blade you can log in to other stack exchange with the same login as here.  They will connect the two together somehow.